# Serialize Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to serialize the reference (not an instance) of an angular component. For example, if I have the following Component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'component-selector',
  template: ...
})
export class CustomComponent {
```

I need to save a reference to it like this:

```js
class CustomClass {
  component: Type<CustomComponent> = CustomComponent;

  ...
}
```

At this point, everything works as expected, and I can use the component as I need. The problem now is that I need to serialize the `CustomClass` and save it to a file.

When I try to do `JSON.stringify(customClass)`, the field `component` is disappearing and if I try to parse the string with `JSON.parse`, results in a `customClass` instance with `undefined` `component`.

I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anvaka/3815296) in order to serialize and deserialize a function, but it didn't work for me (I guess although `Type` interface extends from `Function`, is not the same, isn't it?)

How can I serialize the Angular Component?

Comment: I am looking for an answer as well.

Comment: @PauloPedroso I found a workaround, see answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround (the only solution I found for this) and is creating a mapping from a string (identifier) to the component. For example, in some part of the code we have something like this:

```js
let mapping = [
  {name: 'component1', component: Component1},
  {name: 'component1', component: Component1},
  ...
]
```

So, when the object is stringified, you can save the string that identifies the component, and when you convert it into an object again, you look in the map for the component reference. It works perfectly!