# Angular (9) cache component as it would be rendered to allow fast switching

Tags: angular, plotly

I'm using Plotly.js, and the component for Angular (https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js). Overall, the component for Angular is generally much easier to work with than the raw JS api, but with that I think comes certain limitations.

Is there a way to cache an Angular component when it is rendered, so that if I display it again, calculations associated with the component do not need to be run again? I want to quickly switch between a set of components without waiting for the rendering each time.

I understand that Angular principles and structural directive favour dynamic addition or removal of a component which will add or remove it from the DOM completely. However, this would destroy the associated data, which I explicitly want to avoid.

I came across this: [Serialize Angular Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339414/serialize-angular-component) which mentions the possibility of serializing a component. If I do that, I could store the component in a service and recall it as desired. Can this be done or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: is it rendered always in one place? if no than you won't be able to do that without bugs because of nature of angular change detection

Comment: Yes, ideally I would like to render all components in the same location each time. My other attempt was to try rendering the component in an absolute/fixed placed div, and overlap the divs. Then I could toggle the component visibility, but that seemed to not allow the Plotly graph to be responsive and properly use up the component space.

Comment: when does your component disappear so you wan't to take "cached" component at some point?

Comment: Well, my initial plan was to have a range slider or array of buttons. The index of the range, or id of the button would select the visible component.